# How to identify the type of phrase?

Tags: phrases, morphology

Sometimes, the phrases that I analyze look like they fit more than one category, and other times I do not understand why a phrase is a certain type. (We are taught 5 types: NP, VP, PP, AdjP, AdvP.)

For example:

> “Jeff did it **for no particular reason**“

To me, this looks like a prepositional phrase, due to the presence of the word “for”. But apparently it is an Adjectival Phrase (AdjP). How is this? How does one correctly identify the core of a phrase?

Why is “particular” the core/head? It doesn’t seem like an important part of the phrase, as I could remove it and it would still make sense.

Comment: Jeff did it; what for/ why?  For no reason. It is an adv phrase. It can answer the question for whom too; then it functions as a noun phrase. It is like, Jeff did it for Jack/ for a good cause, etc.  How is it an adj. phrase?

Comment: Phrases are still more if you include 'infinitive phrase, participial phrase/ prepositional phrase, etc.

Comment: Prepositional phrases have a *use*, generally either as an adjective or an adverb.  I would say that the above prepositional phrase modifies "did" and hence is adverbial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrases can be classified in two aspects,according to my grammar book.

1.Classified by considering their functions.

- noun phrase
- verb phrase
- adjective phrase
- adverb phrase

2.Classied by considering just their written forms.For example,If you see the phrase having preposition at the beginning of it,It's a prepositional phrase.

- prepositional phrase
- participial phrase
- gerund phrase
- absolute phrase

I hoped this help....